# interceptor causing 304 response

Tags: angular

I have an interceptor for adding the JWT to each request as follows:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from '../core/services/storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    token: string;

    constructor(
        private storageService: StorageService
    ) {
        this.token = storageService.tokenString;
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.token) {
            const addToken = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('token', this.token),
            });
            return next.handle(addToken);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }

}
```

and it is then provided in the app.module.ts as follows:

```
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AdminGuard,
    ManagerGuard,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: TokenInterceptor,
        multi: true,
    },
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
]
```

this is resulting in a 304 error so the request url should look like this...
`http://localhost:3000/api/users/getAllUsers?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NzA2LCJlbWFpbCI6InNhbmRyYUB0ZW5kZXNpZ24udXMiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjkyNzcxOTJ9.j6gOzGN02vvOPMKgtcFSaVkrm00bGCfqV8isCUVZKVs`

and when i look in my network tab I can confirm that the token is not being added

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you are adding headers wrong

```
        const addToken = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('token', this.token),
        });
```

should be

```
        const addToken = req.clone({
            headers: {token:this.token},
        });
```

2) You stated that

> equest url should look like this...
>   http://localhost:3000/api/users/getAllUsers?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NzA2LCJlbWFpbCI6InNhbmRyYUB0ZW5kZXNpZ24udXMiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjkyNzcxOTJ9.j6gOzGN02vvOPMKgtcFSaVkrm00bGCfqV8isCUVZKVs

It won't look like that with current codebase - you are adding **headers** in the interceptor, and your statement states that it should be added as **query parameter**

Also double check that `this.token` is actually set in the interceptor as it is the condition of actual request modification - it might be falsy.

Comment: headers: req.headers.set('token', this.token) is correct